# Prove that a formula defines a dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Let ***V*** be vector space on the field ℝ of all two-dimensional column vectors. Choose whether or not a transformation $$\left\langle { - | - } \right\rangle :V \times V \to ℝ,$$ defined by a formula $$\left\langle {u\left| v \right.} \right\rangle  = {u^T} \cdot A \cdot v$$ where A is equal to\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}
defines a dot product.

I know that these conditions must be true:$$\left\langle {u|v} \right\rangle  = \left\langle {v|u} \right\rangle $$
$$\left\langle {u + v|w} \right\rangle  = \left\langle {u|w} \right\rangle  + \left\langle {v|w} \right\rangle $$
$$\left\langle {u|u} \right\rangle  \ge 0 \wedge \left\langle {u|u} \right\rangle  = 0 \Leftrightarrow u = {0_V}.$$

I got stuck on the first one:
$$\left\langle {u\left| v \right.} \right\rangle  = {u^T} \cdot A \cdot v$$
$$\left\langle {v\left| u \right.} \right\rangle  = {v^T} \cdot A \cdot u$$ but $${u^T} \cdot A \cdot v \ne {v^T} \cdot A \cdot u$$ And I was also wondering if ***A*** has to be positive definite. Also, how do I prove the second part of the third condition?

Edit:
There is another condition I forgot (but trivial to prove):
$$\left\langle {\alpha  \cdot u\left| v \right.} \right\rangle  = \alpha  \cdot \left\langle {u\left| v \right.} \right\rangle $$

Comment: Those two terms are actually the same. You might try to write $u^t = (a \ \ b)$ and  $v^t = (c\ \ d)$ and calculate.

Comment: Notice that $A$ is symmetric and $x^TAy$ is symmetric for any vectors $x,y$ since this is just a scalar. Thus, $$u^TAv=(u^TAv)^T=v^TA^T(u^T)^T=v^TAu.$$

Comment: @ArcticChar Had they given me a pair of 80-dimensional vectors and 80x80 matrix it would be oblivious to do it this way. Is there any way to prove the first condition without concretizing the vectors?

Comment: @Dave Please elaborate on $${u^T} \cdot A \cdot v = {\left( {{u^T} \cdot A \cdot v} \right)^T}$$ I don't get it from what you said. And what do you mean that A is a scalar?

Comment: That holds because $u^t A v$ is a $1\times 1$, so the transpose equal itself. @tomashauser

Comment: As Arctic Char says: for any $u,v\in\mathbb R^n$ and $n\times n$ real matrix $A$, we have $u^TAv$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix since $u^T$ is $1\times n$ and $v$ is $n\times 1$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first condition, you can use that $A$ is a symmetric matrix.

$$\langle u|v\rangle = u^TA v = (u^TAv)^T = v^TA^T(u^T)^T = v^TAu = \langle v|u\rangle$$

Where we have used that for any scalar $r$ that $r = r^T$, $A = A^T$, and the rule for the transpose of a product.

For the second one we have

$$\langle u + v|w\rangle = (u + v)Aw^T = (u + v)(Aw^T) = uAw^T + vAw^T = \langle u|w\rangle + \langle v|w\rangle$$

This follows from the distributive property of matrix multiplication.

For the third one, we need to be a bit more careful.

Let $u = [a,b]^T$. Then we get

$$\langle u,u\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2 &-1\\ -1 &2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2a-b & 2b-a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix} \\ = (2a^2 - ab) + (2b^2 - ab) = a^2 + b^2 + (a-b)^2 \geq 0$$

From the expanded expression it is clear that only when $a=0, b=0$ will $<u|u>= 0.$

Since we have satisfied all three conditions the transformation does define the dot product.

To answer your question about positive definite, yes for this to work for a matrix it must be positive definite since otherwise, some vectors could have negative dot products with themselves. Positive semidefinite also doesn't work since there may be non-zero vectors which have zero dot product.

Edit (tomashauser):

The last condition:
$$\left\langle {\alpha u\left| v \right.} \right\rangle  = {\left( {\alpha u} \right)^T}Av = {\alpha ^T}{u^T}Av = \alpha {u^T}Av = \alpha \left\langle {u\left| v \right.} \right\rangle $$

Comment: Thank you. So I should also check for pisitive definitnes of A for the solution to be correct, right?

Comment: For a general A you will need to check that it is positive definite to ensure that the third condition is satisfied. By expanding it out to an expression that is clearly positive for all but the zero vector we are showing that it is positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

In general $u^TAv \neq v^TAv$  but this will be true if the row space and the column space are the same. That's always the case for symmetric matrices real valued matrices and $A$ is such a matrix. To see this we just note that $u^TAv=(u^TAv)^T = v^TA^Tu=v^TAu$ with the first equality being true because the transpose of a scalar is a scalar, the second equality by the usual properties of the transpose and the final equality because $A$ is symmetric.

To prove the case $\left\langle {u|u} \right\rangle  = 0 $ we note that $A$ is invertible, so it represents and injective (bijective) map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself and so $Au = 0$ if and only if $u=0$. The same argument holds for $v^TA$ with a row vector instead of a column vector and that show $\left\langle {u|u} \right\rangle  = 0$ only when $u=0$.

Comment: The equality $${u^T} \cdot A \cdot v = {\left( {{u^T} \cdot A \cdot v} \right)^T}$$ comes from the property of A's symmetricity?

Comment: @tomashauser yes. In general if I have some matrices multiplied as $ABC$ then the transpose is $(ABC)^T=C^TB^TA^T$ and for all symmetric matrices $A=A^T$ by definition.